# Excel total values (meeting given criteria) by row id

Tags: excel

I have a Results column with values between 0 and 100 (inclusive). Each row has an identifier (Location). For a result to Pass, it must be greater than or equal to 50. I'd like to total the Passes for each Location.

How would I go about doing that? And is there a name for this form of operation?
See image for example.

Thanks

The cells highlighted in yellow are the aim of this question.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w84I9.png)

Comment: Please add what you try, show samples inline as formated data, Maybe CSV? SO people can copy and check out their helpfull answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a COUNTIFS function:

```
=COUNTIFS($D$4:$D$14,">=50",$C$4:$C$14,F4)
```

Place that in G4 and copy down

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Will do when I'm able to